# How to retrieve the coordinates of the building (length, width, height) on google maps or bing maps?

Tags: c#, google-maps, dictionary, coordinates, bing-maps

I wonder if it is possible with google maps or bing maps to retrieve the coordinates of the buildings? their positions (latitude and longitude) and height of buildings if possible?

If we can recover **the angle of view** and **the perspective** used we should be able to calculate the height Approximate not?

I already searched on the web, but apparently it is not possible to get all this information?
A thousand thank you

Preferably in c # ^ ^

Comment: Don't think it's possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140895/get-height-of-a-building-from-a-maps-api

Comment: Ok thank you. But I do not necessarily seek to recover a precise exact height! But just Approximate!
If we can recover the angle of view and the perspective used we should be able to calculate the height Approximate not?

Comment: I've not come across anything that provides this, but I am sure it is out there somewhere

Comment: This really interested me !! ^^

Comment: Here you'll find some interesting information about Bird's eye view on Bing Maps and methods to calculate distance based on the actual projection. See: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/birds-eye-routes/

I don't think it would be that precise still.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this but they are not perfectly accurate and may have legal issues. Using the Birdseye imagery in Bing Maps gives you an angled view of buildings which technically there is a lot of math that could be done to get the height of the building. However, using Birdseye imagery to do this is against the terms of use of Bing Maps and is a restriction put in place by the data provider for birds eye imagery.

Another method is to use the old Bing Maps 23D control and mouse events to get the altitude of the clicked location. I wrote a blog post on this a long time ago here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/bing-map-3d-altitude-extraction-via-mouse-click/

Bing Maps has a new 3D map control which is currently in preview as a Windows 8 app. There is no public API at this time but if this is for a proof of concept or demo you could always try playing around with the dll's. Here is a blog post on how to do that: http://sharpgis.net/post/2014/01/28/The-layout-of-an-ExtensionSDK